# What is the relationship among FFmpeg, librtmp and rtmpdump?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am a beginner of FFmpeg. I can see that video can be pushed to an [RTMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) server by FFmpeg or librtmp on the Internet. But I also see that when compiling FFmpeg, I need to add option *enable-librtmp*. Are they parallel or inclusive? What is rtmpdump? Does the libtrmp API use RTMP lower-level functions directly?

Comment: The last question was incomprehensible. Is it representative now of the original intent? If not, can you [change it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65366675/edit)? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen you are right, It is representative now of the original intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rtmpdump is a separate project that provides RTMP and related protocols functionality. librtmp is its library form.

FFmpeg has its own set of native RTMP protocol handlers. You can use either in FFmpeg. Adding `-enable-librtmp` during configure will disable the native protocols.

rtmpdump is no longer actively developed; FFmpeg is. On that basis, I would prefer the native handlers.

Comment: I also recommend the native FFmpeg RTMP protocol implementation. One less dependency. A long time ago librtmp was more useful, but the native implementation is mature enough that it doesn't really make a difference for most users. The native implementation has a few more options. FFmpeg development is very active. rtmpdump is not. In my opinion it's about time to consider removing librtmp support.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for your wonderful answer, but as you said,ffmpeg rtmp is better than rtmpdump rtmp, but I met a question, when I check the information on the Internet, it seems that rtmpdump rtmp is better than ffmpeg rtmp, that is RTMP_ XXX  API.(question link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65355580/how-to-push-the-h-264-format-data-received-from-socket-to-rtmp-server)

Comment: @ llogan also thanks for your wonderful reply, stackoverflow can't @ two people at the same time, so I add another comment to ask you for the same question.